# Class property empty in new class instance

Tags: vb.net, class

When I create a class instance using the syntax below, TheProperty is empty when I try to use it inside the Sub New method.

```
    Public Class TheClass
        Public TheProperty As String
        Public Sub New()
            <Do something with TheProperty>
        End Sub
    End Class

    Module TheModule
        Sub Main()
            Dim myClass as New TheClass With {.TheProperty = "value"}
        End Sub
    End Module
```

I know I can set the value of TheProperty before calling the New method, but it has to be possible to get it working this way? I have seen this way of creating class instances before, but have never seen inside those classes. What am I missing?

Comment: The `Sub New` is not a method but it's the constructor. That is used to initialize the instance of the class. At this time all fields and properties are not yet initialized, that's the purpose of the constructor.

Comment: But I can use the constructor to set properties in a streamwriter for instance: Dim sw As New StreamWriter With {.AutoFlush = True}. How is this different?

Comment: For the record, that's not a property. It's a field. If you want it to be a property then you need to declare it as a property, which you should absolutely do if it's public.

Answer (score 1):

The `Sub New` is not a method but it's the constructor. That is used to initialize the instance of the class.

If you want "to do something with the property" there, you need to provide a constructor for it:

```
Public Class TheClass
    Public TheProperty As String

    Public Sub New(theProperty As string)
        Me.TheProperty = theProperty
    End Sub

End Class


Public Sub Main(args() As String)
     Dim x As TheClass = New TheClass("value")
End Sub
```

Now it is ensured that the property is initialized. You *could* also let the default constructor remain, but then it's possible that you have an instance where the property is not initialied, so is `Nothing`.

To clarify the issue in case you still don't understand why your code doesnt work: This code

```
Dim myClass as New TheClass With {.TheProperty = "value"}
```

Is the same as (it's actually "syntactic sugar")

```
Dim myClass as New TheClass()
myClass.TheProperty = "value"
```

Now you can see that in the (default) constructor of the class, the property is not yet initialized.